# How to make C++ run only numbers in a Stack<String^>

Tags: c++-cli

I've got this declaration for using Text, however I need to make it so it works only with numbers with(,)decimals and now I'm stuck...

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: Stack<String^>^ talen;
    public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        talen = gcnew Stack<String^>();
        }
```

'

```
private: System::Void btnPush_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    String^ tal = tbxTal->Text;
    talen->Push(tal);
    tbxIn->AppendText(tal + "\n");
    tbxTal->Text = "";
}

private: System::Void Pop_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    while (talen->Count!=0)
    {
        String^ tal = talen->Pop();
        tbxUt->AppendText(tal + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is c++/cli, not pure c++.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string contains a valid number, I'd make use of one of the `TryParse` methods available.

Perhaps something like this with [`Int32::TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-lang=cpp). Of course, you could use [`Single::TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), [`UInt16::TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxy94716.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), for whatever type of number you like.

```
int value;
String^ tal = tbxTal->Text;
if(Int32::TryParse(tal, value))
{
    tbxIn->AppendText(tal + "\n");
    tbxTal->Text = "";
    talen->Push(tal);
}
else
{
    // Show an error.
}
```

If the only thing you're doing with the stack is what you've shown in `Pop_Click`, then the `Stack<String^>^` is fine, but if you're doing other stuff with it, do consider using a `Stack<int>^` (or whatever datatype you choose) instead.